# Recurrence relation of sum with binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

Is there any way of solving for S(n) to obtain a formula that isn't a recurrence relation for: $$S(n)=\frac{ 1}{4 }\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{ n}{m }S(m)$$
The initial condition is: $S(0)=\frac{\pi^2}{6 }$

Comment: Are you sure it's written up correctly? When $m = n$, $S(n)$ is on both sides.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó  i have edited the question looking back at where the relation came from.

Comment: $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is a very specific value, perhaps some context why that might help to solve this. Did you try to see what pattern emerges if you eliminate $S(n)$ from the RHS, i.e. when $$S(n)=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{m}S(m)$$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take $S(x)=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty}S(m)\frac{x^m}{m!},$ then $$S(x)e^x=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^m}{n!}\sum _{m+k=n}\binom{n}{m}S(m)=4(S(x)-S(0))+S(0)=4S(x)-3S(0),$$ so $$S(x)=\frac{3S(0)}{4-e^x},$$
can you conclude? If not, take a look at [**Eulerian Polynomials.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number)